# The "_cake_model_" cache configuration does not exist after CakePHP upgrade 3.3.16 > 3.6.7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am getting the error:

`The "_cake_model_" cache configuration does not exist.`

after upgrading from CakePHP v3.3.16 to 3.6.7.

However the cache configuration does exist, this from config/app.php:

```
'Cache' => [
    '_cake_model_' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine',
        'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_model_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+2 minutes',
        'url' => env('CACHE_CAKEMODEL_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if that configuration data ends up in Cache with `Cache::getConfig('_cake_model_')` towards the end of your application bootstrap. If that fails your configuration data is likely not getting passed into `Cache`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was NULL in the "className" position. The change below corrected the error.

```
  'className' => 'File'
```

Maybe then there is a problem with correct reading of the className field.